# VFS Global: GWF Reference Number not recognized?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, uk-visa, family

I'm applying for UK fiance visa, have booked appointment on visa4uk website but can't seem to register with VFS Global online using my GWF number. Instead, they generate an 11 digit number that starts with the letter "F" instead of the GWF number provided by visa4uk.

Does anyone know what can be done about this? My appointment is in 2 days and I need to be able to register with them before going to VFS global and submitting my documents... Thanks.

Comment: Did you apply through https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply?

Comment: @Traveller The link you're asking about is for standard visitor visas, while the question is about a fiance visa.

Comment: @phoog Sorry I meant https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/alt-language-selection-skip-visa Basically applying via gov.uk and not visa4uk